# How to use minifyEnable in release apk?

Tags: android, react-native, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my code using Proguard, but when I set minifyEnable to true, my release apk crashs. Here is my build.gradle:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
```

(enableProguardInReleaseBuilds is true)

I also tried to add some configs to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
```

But it didn't worked.

The log error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fill
        at com.horcrux.svg.b0.U(:629)
        at com.horcrux.svg.l.b0(:100)
        at com.horcrux.svg.l.E(:81)
        at com.horcrux.svg.b0.N(:339)
        at com.horcrux.svg.f0.G(:304)
        at com.horcrux.svg.f0.H(:255)
        at com.horcrux.svg.f0.onDraw(:106)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21421)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21424)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21424)
        at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.draw(HorizontalScrollView.java:1745)
        at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.d.draw(:560)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21424)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21424)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21424)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.f.dispatchDraw(:685)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
2021-08-04 10:35:25.577 25098-25098/com.pay4fun.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fill
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1604)
        at com.horcrux.svg.b0.U(:620)
            ... 111 more
```

Could some one help me here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add:

```
-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}
```

in proguard-rules.pro (android/app/proguard-rules.pro)

more detail in [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1061)

Comment: Can you give a brief summary or excerpt from the link, in case it becomes broken?

Comment: This is the "react-native-SVG" making the app crash (if you remove the fill prop and build the APK it runs normally) @ryanwebjackson.  but I suggested the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Build gradle should be like this

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard- 
android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')'
```

In you code after obfuscation field name changes and maybe you have data feild or any class which should not be obfuscated try figure out that

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried this, but didn't worked